# Proper way to organize blocks of code within a class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have a class in a Sidekiq worker that has blocks of code that I'd love to move into separate files for organizational purposes. How would I do that?

```
# /app/workers/pull_data_worker.rb
class PullDataWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(account_id)
    account = Account.find(account_id)

    # Chunk A
    # block of code that does something

    # Chunk B
    # block of code that does something

    # Chunk C
    # block of code that does something
  end
end
```

Each of those "chunks" is just various blocks of code that process some data. They aren't methods are anything. Just basic things that loop through some data pulled from different third-party APIs.

So, what's the proper way to separate those?

Running Ruby 2.0.0 on a Rails 4.0.1 app.

Comment: why don't you make private methods for each block?

Comment: Do you have duplication of this same block of code in other workers?

Comment: @Vimsha No. It's more of a "holy crap the code in this file is getting insanely long, I'd love to separate it in to smaller chunks".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least the choice of extract into `methods`, `classes` or `modules`. All this falls into the task of refactoring, for which nice tutorials and books are written, giving rationales about which path to choose.

In my opinion, start extracting methods and see what consequences it has. Its hard to judge based on your limited example. Given robbrits answer, you could also define the method for the very same class (PullDataWorker) in another file - for sake of maintainability I would not do that though - somebody might end up not knowing that additional methods are defined somewhere else.

```
class PullDataWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include ThisProject::ChunkC

 def perform(account_id)
    account = Account.find(account_id)

    # Extracted method, see below.
    do_chunk_a account

    # From other class, see below.
    ChunkBDoer.new.do_stuff

    # From module ThisProject::ChunkC .
    chunkC_do_stuff
  end

  private

  def do_chunk_a(account)
  end
end

class ChunkBDoer
  def do_stuff
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby you have the concept of "open classes", which means that when you define code in a class across multiple files, it doesn't really matter.

Say you have one file like this (a.1.rb):

```
class A
  def foo1
    # some stuff
  end
end
```

Then another file like this (a.2.rb):

```
class A
  def foo2
    # some stuff
  end
end
```

Then from anywhere:

```
require_relative "path/to/a.1"
require_relative "path/to/a.2"

a = A.new
a.foo1
a.foo2
```

When you require a.2.rb, it *merges* the existing definition of `A` with the new definition of `A`, so it will add any new methods defined or overwrite any existing ones.

Comment: But does that work when the blocks of code are part of a method in a class? In my example, the blocks of code I'm trying to pull out into their own file are all inside the `perform()` method.

Comment: You'll have to pull those blocks out into their own methods, and then call the methods from `perform`. Provided that you have required the extra file(s) before the first time `perform` is called, then it will work fine.